# Google Drive REST API v2 file properties array in Google Apps Script is undefined?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I am working to manage some Google Drive files with Google Apps Script. One piece of this project is reviewing properties on files, so I am using the Drive API rather than DriveApp. Additionally, Google Apps Script currently has access to the [Drive REST API v2](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/about-sdk) instead of v3.

I've successfully set a property (id) and am able to pull the files with the property set.

```
console = Logger;
function Files (folderId) {
  var optionalArgs,response
  ;
  optionalArgs = {
    q:'"'+folderId+'" in parents',
    spaces:"drive"
  }
  do {
    response = Drive.Files.list(optionalArgs);
    response.items.forEach(function (file) {
      console.log(file.properties);
      var id = file.properties.find(function (property) {
        return property.key === 'id';
      });
      this[id.value] = file;
    },this);
  } while (optionalArgs.pageToken = response.nextPageToken);
}
```

When running this function, I am able to see the file properties in the log

> [{visibility=PUBLIC, kind=drive#property, etag="3GjDSTzy841RsmcBo4Ir-DLlp20/HGzJl78t8I2IehiAlaGXTkm2-C4", value=9e18766b-1cc9-4c1b-8003-b241f43db304, key=id}]

but get

> TypeError :Cannot call method "find" of undefined.

I am unable to iterate through this resulting array. Using JSON.parse on it trys to convert it to an object, which is problematic for files with multiple properties. Using JSON.parse(JSON.stringify()) on it results in

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token: u

which I understand is resulting from the value being undefined. I could work with that, if my log wasn't telling me otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

"nextPageToken(string)  The page token for the next page of files. **This will be absent if the end of the files list has been reached.**"

Quote from: https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list#examples

so this line assigns an undefined value to optionalArgs.pageToken

```
while (optionalArgs.pageToken = response.nextPageToken);
```

and does not terminate the loop. A better way is to assign the value of optionalArgs.pageToken inside the loop and break the loop if its value is undefined like this:

```
console = Logger;
function Files (folderId) {
  var optionalArgs,response
  ;
  optionalArgs = {
    q:'"'+folderId+'" in parents',
    spaces:"drive"
  }
  do {
    response = Drive.Files.list(optionalArgs);
    response.items.forEach(function (file) {
      console.log(file.properties);
      var id = file.properties.find(function (property) {
        return property.key === 'id';
      });
      this[id.value] = file;
    },this);
// Assign the value inside the loop
optionalArgs.pageToken = response.nextPageToken
} while (optionalArgs.pageToken != undefined) // check to see if it undefined here and break the loop.
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the more accepted method to assign the value, however that is not the issue I am encountering. Additionally, it does actually terminate the loop when expected.

Answer (score 0):

You can use v3 in Google Apps Script by selecting the version in the Advance Google Service option:

[image]
Just note that you have to follow how to request in Google Drive v3 but you can still use v2 because all of the example is still in v2.

Regarding your error, using their code in the sample code for [Listing folders](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive#listing_folders).

```
function listRootFolders() {
  var query = '"root" in parents and trashed = false and ' +
      'mimeType = "application/vnd.google-apps.folder"';
  var folders, pageToken;
  do {
    folders = Drive.Files.list({
      q: query,
      maxResults: 100,
      pageToken: pageToken
    });
    if (folders.items && folders.items.length > 0) {
      for (var i = 0; i < folders.items.length; i++) {
        var folder = folders.items[i];
        Logger.log('%s (ID: %s)', folder.title, folder.id);
      }
    } else {
      Logger.log('No folders found.');
    }
    pageToken = folders.nextPageToken;
  } while (pageToken);
}
```

You can also read more code implementation of the above documentation.

Hope this helps.